# Need to Run code on all excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()
    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
 
    'Select folder in which all files are stored
    fDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = currWb.path
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
      folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    
    'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = False
    
    'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While fileName <> ""
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & folderName & "\" & fileName
 
 
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(folderName & "\" & fileName)
        
'... Code here
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            xWs.Delete
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'... code ends here

        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True 'Close opened worbook w/o saving, change as needed
        Debug.Print "Processed " & folderName & "\" & fileName
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
    eApp.Quit
    Set eApp = Nothing
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Completed executing macro on all workbooks"
End Sub
```

I tried running this code on all files in a folder. Had 34 files in a folder and wanted to delete all sheets except the sheet named "Sheet1" from each file

Comment: any reason you are opening a 2nd Excel instance?

Comment: At least make the second instance visible so you can see what's going on while you debug your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Workbok `wb` is in Excel instance `eApp`. It's different with `Application.ActiveWorkbook`

Change a line code as below.

```
    For Each xWs In wb.Worksheets
```

Comment: It shows "Completed executing macro on all workbooks" however the files are same as before. No procedure happened there. 
I also tried changing the variable from "Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet"
to "Dim wb As Workbook, xws As Worksheet"

and removing this variable declaration from code line.

Comment: `wb.Close SaveChanges:=True` should save the workbook. Adding `Debug.Print fileName` to validate if your code gets the file list correctly. Run the code with F8 is helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: ... or simply use the debugger.